# AWS: Same VPC, but can only access one DB

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, security-groups

I am fairly new to AWS, so I am sure that I am just missing something, but here is my problem:

I have created a VPC with 3 subnets and one security group linked to all of them. The security group accepts inbound  from my machine.
Next I have created to RDS (both PostgreSQL) into that VPC and added linked them to the VPC security group. Weirdly, I can only connect to one of them, for the other one I get a generic error.

Any idea on what I am missing?
I can share any more details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that either both RDS don't have the same / correct Security Group, or the VPC subnets have different route tables that prevent access to one of the RDS instances.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment!
They actually have the exact same security groups and subnets. Which is why I am so confused.

Comment: @Lennart when you say the other one returns “generic error” what does that mean? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Message is as follow:
could not connect to server: Connection timed out. Is the server running on host "******.rds.amazonaws.com" (**.***.**.***) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: @Lennart as noted in the answer, all the subnets also need the same route table if they are all used for the same purpose.  Confirm this?

Comment: Yes, same route table for all subnets. The two DBs are using the same subnets though. Can that be a problem?